# Entity framework, struggling with pulling back and displaying information from list/collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I've been following examples online and have written the following. The combobox works fine and the ID pulls back fine.

Question 1: Do I always need to use a foreach loop to access the data in the list that is created

```
    impactmodel context = new impactmodel();
    var information = from i in context.Sites
                      where i.Site_ID == value
                      select i;

    foreach (var item in information)
    {
        textBox3.Text = item.Site_DisplayName;
        textBox2.Text = item.Site_Fax_Number.ToString();
    }
```

Now I know that there is only one result in information, but I can't access it like:

```
information.Site_DisplayName;
information.Site_Fax_Numeber.ToString();
```

Is there any easier way to do this when there is only one result returned?

Question 2: I have another table that is also linked in the entity model called contracts. I thought this would be easy to get a value from this through Lazy Loading (it is implicitly associated to my Sites table in the model) but I am having to do a join in a linq query, make that into a list and then mess about with that with a foreach loop to get the values out.

Is there not an easier way to do this? I expect I am missing something basic here.

Comment: Question 1: `information.First()` or if `Site_ID` is the primary key, you can do `.Signle()`. As for your second question, I don't know what your requirements are but you can define `Contracts` as a [Navigation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) in your model that is joined with your `Sites`. You should be able to do that in the designer without having having to write your own join query. The other method would be to use a stored procedure.

Comment: if(information.Any())
   {
    bla = information.First();
    }

Comment: Question 1 is now sorted - thanks. For question two the navigation property is already there, I just want to know how to access it in the quickest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do:

```
var information = context.Sites.Single(x => x.Site_ID == value);
```

Then `information` will be the item you want and not a collection containing just the single item you want.  Be aware this will fail if there isn't exactly one item.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question look at the `.Include("NavigationPropery")` or `.Include(x=>x.NavigationProperty)` Something like

```
from o in context.Order.Include(x=>x.OrderRow)
where o.Id == someValue
where 0.OrderRow.Id == someOtherValue
select o
```